# How to make specific imageView reply to simple gesture listener, how to link onTouchListener to simpleGestureListener?

Tags: touch-event, gesture-recognition, ontouch, gesturelistener

I dont' know how to connect onTouchListener to SimpleOnGestureListener, because onTouchlistener only accepts its own type - touchlistener.

the way I have done it is this: onTouchEvent(not specific imageView's onTouch) gives the event to gestureDetector object to process.

This results in **activity** being able to detect fling, doubletap and other simple gestures.

**But i only want specific imageView to respond and recognize doubleTap**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private class Erjan_gestures extends SimpleOnGestureListener{

    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.wtf("x", "double tap occured!");
        return true ;
    }
}

Button button;
ImageView image ;

GestureDetector gestureDetector;
int oldW , oldH ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.card);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    oldW = 500;
    oldH = 600;

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new Erjan_gestures());
    gestureDetector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);


    image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.wtf("x", "card's onTouch");
            //HOW TO CONNECT this ontouch to simple gesturelistener(class above)?
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    Log.wtf("x", "-------------------------------onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)");
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event) ;
}
```

}

How do I connect image onTouch to recognize simple gestures?

Answer (score 0):

I found no better solution than to just check for coordinates of motionEvent:

```
private class Erjan_gestures extends SimpleOnGestureListener{
@Override
        public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
            float e_x = e.getRawX();
            float e_y = e.getRawY();
            if(e_x > 1360 && e_x < 1733 && e_y > 465 && e_y < 1028){
                doubleTapHappened = true ;//DESIRED ACTION
                Log.wtf("x", "double tap occured on CARD!");
            }

            return true ;
        }
```

I can't yet write my own custom views that respond to gestures in the desired fashion. So i just check for **where the tap occurred**.